# What does Rows indicate in the explain plan?

Tags: oracle

This was my query:

```
SELECT payload_data FROM staging_record WHERE record_source = 11;
```

This was the execution plan:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                  |  9016 |  1875K|   292   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| STAGING_RECORD   |  9016 |  1875K|   292   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IX_RECORD_SOURCE |  9016 |       |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("RECORD_SOURCE"=11)
```

I did a count and it returned `22619` with this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staging_record WHERE record_source = 11;
```

Why does Rows column say 9016 when my count returned 22619. What is `Rows` refering to here?

Answer (score 3):

The figure of 9016 is the optimizer's *estimate* based on the statistics it has.  If the table has 901,600 rows and there are 100 distinct values for record_source, then the optimizer may estimate that a typical query by record_source will return 901,600/100 = 9016 rows.  Skewing of the actual data may make this innacurate (it will never be perfect).  If the data is quite skewed then histograms can be used to refine the statistics further.

Comment: I would just add that the fact that the estimate is not correct is not necessarily a problem.  If the query is using a reasonable execution plan that performs well, it is probably fine.  If the estimate were off by an order of magnitude or more, that would be more likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your indicies are obsolete. Refresh stats (using `DBMS_STATS`) and you'll get more accurate value.

`Rows` refers to the amount of rows being affected during query execution (approximate, according to the indicies info).

Comment: How do i update my stats? Is that via ANALYZE TABLE staging_record COMPUTE STATISTICS? Because that didn't help :|

Comment: @JavaRocky: find some `DBMS_STATS` sample. For now I'm already at home and haven't any complete commands.

Comment: While it's possible that the statistics are out of date, there's no clear evidence here that that's the reason.  Per Tony's answer, the larger issue is how complete a picture the statistics give of the actual data.

Comment: @Dave Costa: oops, yes, forgot that `rows` actually is a `cardinality`